# Subtraction Data in mysql with category and sub category its posible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating model data, but i to make data like table 3, it's posible ?

the calculation is in table 1 has Model A with Part A and Part B which have each number of orders, where the number of orders will be reduced to the remaining stock in table 2 based on Part A, then the same applies to Model B having Part A , where the number of orders will be reduced to the remaining stock in table 2

Table 1

```
| Model | Part | Qty Need |
:-: | :-: | :-: |
Model A | Part A | 5
Model A | Part B | 3
Model B | Part A | 2
Model B | Part B | 4
```

Table 2

```
| Part | Qty Stock |
:-: | :-: |
Part A | 10
Part B | 20
```

I Need data like this,

Table 3

```
| Model | Part | Qty Need | Qty Stock | Qty Sub |
:-: | :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
Model A | Part A | 5 | 10 | 5
Model A | Part B | 3 | 20 | 17
Model B | Part A | 2 | 5 | 3
Model B | Part B | 4 | 17 | 13
```

Anyone can't help ? I'm stuck with this

Comment: Please explain the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to subtract the amounts used from the total quantity in the second table.  If so, you can use cumulative sums:

```
select t1.*,
       t2.qty_stock + t1.part - sum(t1.qty) over (partition by t1.part order by t1.model) as qty_stock,
       t2.qty_stock - sum(t1.qty) over (partition by t1.part order by t1.model) as qty_sub       
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.part = t2.part
```

Comment: Amazing bro Thanks, but its not work at MySQL 5.6 Community, But Work At 10.4.20-MariaDB